# NVIDIA gfx card changes from slot 1 to slot 2 in PulseAudio

Tags: linux-mint, audio, nvidia, pulseaudio

In Linux Mint, I used to have problems with no sound around 50% of the time when I boot up. I found that PulseAudio was looking for my graphics card in the wrong hardware slot. I used...

```
aplay -l
```

...to get the list of cards and ports, test each with...

```
aplay -D plughw:1,3 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
```

...until I get the correct one, and then update my /etc/pulse/default.pa file to correct the correct one, then log out and in again for PulseAudio to work.

However, it's never quite fully been fixed, as sometimes when I log on again it detects my Nvidia card on Slot 1, and other times on Slot 2. so, when the sound doesn't work, I have to change the default.pa file from plughw:1,3 to plughw:2,3 or vice versa depending on where the card is detected.

The example line for the file is currently:

```
load-module module-alsa-sink device=plughw:1,3
```

...a bit more...

```
### Load audio drivers statically
### (it's probably better to not load these drivers manually, but instead
### use module-udev-detect -- see below -- for doing this automatically)
load-module module-alsa-sink device=plughw:1,3
#load-module module-alsa-sink
#load-module module-oss device="/dev/dsp" sink_name=outputsource_name=input
#load-module module-oss-mmap device="/dev/dsp" sink_name=output source_name=input
#load-module module-null-sink
#load-module module-pipe-sink

### Automatically load driver modules depending on the hardware available
.ifexists module-udev-detect.so
load-module module-udev-detect use_ucm=0
.else
### Use the static hardware detection module (for systems that lack udev support)
load-module module-detect
.endif
```

So, I don't know how to autodetect it, I was thinking I could maybe write a script to check for pulse at the beginning, and change the file / restart pulse if it broke, but I wouldn't know how to do this really.

If anyone could offer advice, I'd greatly appreciate it.